# BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty) Equivalent in python?

Tags: c#, python, encryption

How can I write the following line in python?

```
BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty)
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
import random
import uuid
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
import binascii

key = hashlib.sha256(b'SOmeKEyy').digest()
key1 = base64.b64encode(key)
iv_value = b'RandomValuie'
iv = base64.b64decode(iv_value)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)

message = Mac_AddressBytes + ip_address_Bytes + DeviceIdBytes
msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(message)

s =encrypt(message, key)
print(s)

sa = bytearray(s)
DeviceIdentity1 = binascii.b2a_hex(s)
DeviceIdentityDecoded = "0x" + DeviceIdentity1.decode('utf-8')
print (str(DeviceIdentityDecoded))
```

`Mac_AddressBytes + ip_address_Bytes + DeviceIdBytes` is a valid String.

The ouput I am getting here is in hexadecimal which I want but If i run the same string in C# I am getting a diffrent string the part that I am missing in python is the `BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty)`.

I have tried to following:

`DeviceIdentity2 = "0x" + DeviceIdentity1.decode('utf-8').replace("-", "")`

but it gives me back the same value as:

`DeviceIdentityDecoded = "0x" + DeviceIdentity1.decode('utf-8')`

When I Decrpyt the string I am getting the following:

```
Îí5ó/½û.qõX9D&Ç:eXM»Bñj2µ\ëÁ§ÓËÔ¤ý  ¼t®@Z9)Àåñr¹ Ör¾hÅåéÙ|¶nÙZÆÃï,¡WÀj©r{ÆR¥f,|^W¯C
Ù1¾+MöB;S­ô«¹næk0ú·7e,atMìÆ¿Kfí
```

Is there an equivalent in python the c# code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested I have found out that i was missing the PKCS7Encoder()

This is the updated answer that works

```
key = base64.b64decode("SOmeKEyy")
    iv_value = 'RandomValue'
    iv = base64.b64decode(iv_value)
    encoder = PKCS7Encoder()
    padded_text = encoder.encode(secret_text)
    padded_text1 = padded_text.encode()
    print(padded_text1)
    e = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    cipher_text = e.encrypt(padded_text1)
    Finally = binascii.b2a_hex(cipher_text)
    DeviceIdentity = "0x" + Finally.decode('utf-8').replace("-", "")
    print(DeviceIdentity)
```